# jquery selecting specific element and manipulating it

Tags: jquery

ok, bit of a noob question - and more to satisfy my need to understand WHY i cant do this, or how to do it better....

```
$("#hi div").hide();
var temp = $("#hi div")[0];
$(temp).show();
```

This works, fantastic.

```
$("#hi div")[0].show();
```

Why doesnt that work!
Is there a short hand way to do what I need to do, without having to define a variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `[0]`, you're pulling the first DOM element out of the set of elements in the jQuery object. Because DOM elements don't have a native `.show()` function it doesn't work.

The reason the first example works is that you're pulling the DOM element out with `[0]`, but then re-wrapping it with a jQuery objected when you do `$(temp)`. You didn't do that for the second.

If you were hoping to target only the first matched element in the jQuery object, use [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead, which gives you the DOM element wrapped in jQuery.

```
var divs = $("#hi div").hide();
divs.eq(0).show(); // to show the first one

divs.eq(0).hide(); // or to hide it
```

This example stores the wrapped set of elements that were matched in a variable. Then you pull out the ones you want using different jQuery methods. This way you don't need to continuously select the elements from the DOM.

As [@Justus Romijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334243/justus-romijn) noted in a comment below, there are other methods like [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to target a particular matched element, as well as [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that can be used.

```
$("#hi div:first")
```

Which approach to take depends on the circumstance. Ultimately, it is good to avoid a repeated identical DOM selection. Since your first code seems to want to `.hide()` all the targeted divs, I'd store that  in a variable, then pull from that collection as needed (like in my first example).

Comment: `$("#hi div").first().show();` will still do what you want. But this explanation is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Or even simpler:

```
$('#hi div:first').hide(); 
$('#hi div:eq(0)').hide(); //the same
```

Edit: I have looked at jQuery (1.4.2) source and find out:

```
// .first() = eq(0)
first: function() {
    return this.eq( 0 );
},

// eq(i) wrapper around slide method
eq: function( i ) {
    return i === -1 ?
    this.slice( i ) :
    this.slice( i, +i + 1 );
},
// slice is not simple and pushstack method is quite complicated
slice: function() {
        return this.pushStack( slice.apply( this, arguments ),
            "slice", slice.call(arguments).join(",") );
    },
// so:
$('#hi div').slice(1); // does not work - returns all divs
$('#hi div').slice(-1); // returns first div
```

PS. I know is little pointless, but I like to know how stuff works "under the hood"

Comment: Keep in mind that jQuery's pseudo-class-selectors are probably a lot slower than simple selectors combined with jQuery's methods, because the whole expression needs to be parsed by Sizzle.js, then. If you limit your selectors to CSS3, your browser will do the selector-work for you, which is very fast in decent browsers.

Comment: I'd agree with @elusive. Unless the selector is a valid CSS selector, `querySelectorAll` can't use it. If the entire set wasn't needed, a nice quick approach would be to use `.slice()` as in `$('#hi div').slice( 1 )`.

Comment: @elusive so the fastest solution is $('#hi').find('div:first-child').hide(); ? ps. how do you make "code look" in comments?

Comment: The fastest solution is probably `$('#hi div')` (native selector, extremely fast, even in old browsers, since there is no CSS 3), then `.eq(0).hide()` (jQuery methods, which operate on the selected set). In one row: `$('#hi div').eq(0).hide()`. The "code-style" is achieved by wrapping the code in `\`` (backticks) like this: `\`$('#hi div').eq(0).hide()\``

Answer (score 0):

`$("#hi div").children(':first-child').show();`

and you could chain

`$("#hi div").hide().children(':first-child').show();`

Comment: the chain didnt work, im guessing becuase of the children() function.